# Pattern matching with variables

Tags: pattern-matching, sml, stable-identifier

How can I match on variable value. So, I want to write smt like

```
 val x = 2
 val m = (1, 2)
 case m of (_, valueOf(x)) => "same" 
         | (_, _)          => "different"
```

I guess, it named stable identifier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the variable in the `case` expression and the constant in the `of` expression:

```
case (1, x) of (_, 2) => "same"
             | _ => "different"
```

What you can't do in Standard ML is to pattern-match two variables against each other. That will only result in one of them being bound to the value of the other (shadowing the old value of one of the variables). You need to use an `if` expression, or bind the comparison to its own value before the case expression, something like this:

```
let
 val cmp = fn (_, m2) => m2 = x
in
 case cmp m of true  => "same"
             | false => "different"
end
```

Comment: Thanks. But lets assume that I get `(1, 2)` from other variable.